# Recaculating control limits when an out of control situation is displayed

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quality-control, control-chart

When plotting control charts if a point plots outside the control limits then the reason for that point to plot outside is checked and if  an assignable cause is found to be the cause then after removing that point control limits are recalculated.My question what should be done :
1)If a point plots outside the control limits but no assignable cause is found?

2)Also when no point plots outside control limits but it shows an out of control situation(due to non randomness). But the cause for out of control situation could not be found.Then in this case can the control limits obtained can be used for future calculations?

In these situations can the existing control limits be used or should they be recalculated?

Comment: These are excellent questions (+1). Consider removing the [tag:self-study] tag, because they are not routine and I believe they are unlikely to have simple general answers.